# Wait to finish previous execution of method change to execute another

Tags: jquery, ajax, methods

I want to call a change() method after finish call previous change method like this:

```
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceMarca').find('.marca').val(enlaceMarca).change();
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceProducto').find('.producto').change();


$('.marca').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ //ajax call to populate .producto select according a value of marca })
})

$('.producto').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ //ajax call})
})
```

But the problem is that call second change() method of .alcanceProducto without finished first change() method and I need call to second change() just after finished first change().

I don't want put the second call to change() inside the first ajax change(), but I think exists another methods or functions to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options (it depends on requirements and code complexity). First and more naive:

- let's set `async` to `false` for you `ajax()` request, next line of code won't be executed until the first request has been completed (but your page won't refresh too).
- let's put the second call inside the callback (or one of the jQuery helpers methods) of the first one (so it'll be executed when first call ends).
- let's use the `when` function of jQuery (it mimics the request chain you may write by hand).

If your code paths are not so straight and/or you have to handle more tricky situations (for example when multiple requests may be started by user actions) you have to create your own list.

Each `on('change')` handler will not start a request but it'll put it in a FIFO then it'll pop the first entry and it'll execute that one. In the callback function it'll pop next one (and so on if multiple requests has been queued). You can start from [this link](http://positionabsolute.net/blog/2007/04/ajax-request-queue.php) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I would first create functions for your ajax calls the following way :

```
function ajax1(endFunc){
    $.ajax({ //ajax call to populate .producto select according a value of marca })
    .done(function(){
       if(typeof endFunc === "function") 
            endFunc();
     });
}
```

and

```
function ajax2(){
     $.ajax({ //ajax call})
}
```

then I would write the following :

```
ajax1(ajax2);
```

instead of :

```
('#editMPS_structure .alcanceMarca').find('.marca').val(enlaceMarca).change();
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceProducto').find('.producto').change();
```

Don't forget to link your new functions with the onchanges :

```
$('.marca').on('change', ajax1);
$('.producto').on('change', ajax2);
```

That would be my solution. Unfortunately I can't test it right now, but I think it should work. Let me know !

Answer (score 0):

Just hold the deferred returned from the ajax calls in a variable and call done() on that to see if it's done :

```
var ajax = $.ajax(); // avoids calling done() on undefined

$('.marca').on('change', function() {
    ajax = $.ajax({
        url: 'something'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('first'); // will always complete before the next one
    });
});

$('.producto').on('change', function() {
    ajax.done(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'something'
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log('second'); // will always complete after the first one
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahttf/)

Answer (score -1):

hold the setting of the `change` event on .producto until the respose of the first ajax call is complete

```
$('.marca').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ //.... })
      .done(function() { 
        $('.producto').on('change', function() {
          $.ajax({ //ajax call})
```